# Dynamic changed page (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What is the best way to keep data in table on page up to date?

Now i use timer, that connects to server via ajax every 2 seconds and check for changes.

Is there any way to initiate any event or function only on content change from server side?

*P.s. Is there any way to do it without using frameworks? Demo with sources will be perfect.*

Comment: For that you may need sockets there is something called nodejs and a framework called socket.io this way the server will push you only when there is new data.

Comment: Which method sites like stackoverflow.com uses for synchronizing ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that use broker service the server, or add trigger on your data in order to determine changes and use socket programming in order to refresh data on clients.

For example: you can use [SQL Server service broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) in order to update clients, when data changed on your database.

Comment: Give me please some links on examples\documentation, thanks.